# Remove MagSafe magnets from iPhone to avert pacemaker interference

Tags: iphone, apple-watch, magsafe

Is there a way to remove the MagSafe magnets from newer iPhones and Apple Watches?

Magnets in the devices have been reported to be incompatible with medical devices such as pacemakers.

> Apple has listed products it says should be kept a "safe distance" away from medical devices like pacemakers and implanted defibrillators.
>
> https://www.bbc.com/news/technology-57605772

Comment: The magnets are probably not consumer removable as they are integral to the finished products.

Comment: @IconDaemon maybe I should rephrase the question.  Will the phone boot with out qi charging and magnets installed on the phone.

Comment: How do you expect to remove the magnets without destroying the device?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure where they are located so I wasn't aware that being an issue.  Maybe an alternative back for the iPhone or something similar.

Comment: This _is_ a laudable question, but perhaps somewhat more applicable on Physics.se? A lead shield will block magnetism to some extent, depending on its thickness. I know of no commercial lead-shielded back/cover on the market.

Comment: If you would like me to simplify the question we can first narrow down where they are maybe.

Comment: The details are fine William. We’re not a physics site or electrical engineering site, so all those details wouldn’t be appropriate here. For a site covering bio electrical engineering, absolutely it would matter on lead placement, software version of the device, what mode is operations in, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. All iPhones are not user serviceable or modifiable. To me, the concern is more the high powered radio interference than the magnets but I understand both will dramatically affect some implantable defibrillators.

Both effects are clear after 6 inches (15 cm) so the most effective remedy for this is awareness and not charging the devices together. A foot of distance is listed as enough for safety.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211900

Comment: The 11(I believe) is the last iPhone my grandparents are getting.  The 12 shocked him once when brought to close.

Comment: @William If that is actually true, then you have a real problem on your hands. If you mean the implied thing here, namely that the pacemaker shocked your grandparent when brought the phone close, then the pacemaker is malfunctioning and he should contact his doctor immediately. If you mean that the iPhone itself shocked your grandparent then that suggest to me that it was connected to a charger at the time, and the charger is malfunctioning and should be replaced immediately with an original charger.

Comment: @jksoegaard I agree with you in theory except for the part that Apple published a specific page about this which leads me to believe this is quite complex

Comment: @william No, they certainly did not. Is it so that you grand parents was not actually shocked, but you read about problems with pace makers and iPhones, and assumed he would be shocked? (Just to be clear, I’m perfectly aware that Apple published a page about the impact on pace makers - but it definitely does not have to do with shocking anyone)

Comment: @William implantable defibrillators read exceptionally low voltages compared to a cellular radio designed to talk over miles to a cell tower. Urge your relatives to have the leads checked and a tech validate the telemetry from the medical device.

Comment: Just to clear about what the issue is with magnets and pacemakers/ICD: They do not cause shocks. It’s the opposite you need to be worried about. Doctors use magnets to tell the pace maker to go into a kind of “standby” mode in order to communicate with it, change its settings, readout battery level, etc. In this mode it does pace, but if you really need a shock - it doesn’t give you one. However this is not something that happens if you carry a phone in your pockets or have it by your ear. Just don’t keep it in your shirt pocket.

Comment: @jksoegaard It is entirely realistic that a magnets can cause a pacemaker to malfunction in a way that the user would describe as a "shock". Just because he wasn't literally electrocuted doesn't mean that he's lying about having felt the malfunction occur and didn't know how best to describe the sensation.

Comment: We’re not talking about any magnets here - it’s the relatively low-strength ones in the iPhone 12.